# Configure gvim swap, undo, and backup files on windows

Tags: windows-10, vim, gvim, powershell-5.0

I installed `vim` on windows 10 using [`chocolatey`](https://chocolatey.org/). When I edit a  `foo` file in `powershell`, `vim` leaves behind `.foo.un~` or `.foo~` files. What are these and how do I stop `vim` from leaving them around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These files are [`backup`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/607475/9636) and [`undo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27undofile%27) files. `vim` also creates [`swap`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/179) files if it crashes while editing.

From https://coderwall.com/p/sdhfug/vim-swap-backup-and-undo-files

In `powershell`, create the following directories:

```
~/.vim
~/.vim/.undo
~/.vim/.backup
~/.vim/.swp
```

Edit your `.vimrc` file by opening vim and typing:

```
:edit $MYVIMRC
```

Then, add the following lines, and save:

```
set undodir=~/.vim/.undo/
set backupdir=~/.vim/.backup/
set directory=~/.vim/.swp/
```

`vim` will now put your `undo`, `backup`, and `swap` files in the `~/.vim/.undo/`, `~/.vim/.backup/`, and `~/.vim/.swp/` directories, respectively.

Comment: editing $MYVIMRC for me opens `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc` which does not have user permission to write  (i.e. readonly , and force-write fails with permission error)  (although I didn't install via chocolatey as OP did)

Comment: Why is the double forward slash at the end of the path necessary? *EDIT* From a comment in the link: "the "//" at the end of each directory means that file names will be built from the complete path to the file with all path separators substituted to percent "%" sign. This will ensure file name uniqueness in the preserve directory."